# Ruby интерполяция строк

Tags: ruby, интерполяция

На вход функции подаётся строка(пример "1+2+3"), вернуть результат(то есть посчитать).
Я преобразую строку из "14+3" в "#{14+3}". Почему не считает, а оставляет так как есть?

```
def calculateStr(str)
    str.insert(0, "#")
    str.insert(1, "{")
    str.insert(str.size, "}")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы "посчитать" например, "1+2+3", можно проще сделать:

```
eval("1+2+3") # => вернет 6
```

Т.о. в вашем методе надо добавить в конце метода строку(чтобы получить ожидаемый вами результат, вы же просто модифицировали строку до этого)

```
eval(str)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте хоть предупреждение, если предлагаете решение с использованием eval